# My proof towards showing that $g^2 = e$ implies that $G$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I saw this task in my book. 
Suppose we have group, where for all elements we have: $g \cdot g = e = g \cdot g^{-1}$. Prove that this is commutative.

My attempt: for all $a,b \in G a\cdot b = c_{1}$

$ a\cdot a \cdot b = a\cdot c_{1} = b$

$b\cdot a = c_{2}$

$ b\cdot a \cdot a = c_{2} \cdot a = b = a \cdot c_{1}$ now can I say that $c_{1} = c_{2}$?

Comment: Swedish hint: what can you say about $abba$?

Comment: @Bungo $abba = e$?

Comment: Yes, since $a(bb)a = aea = aa = e$. Now can you manipulate $abba = e$ into $ab = ba$?

Comment: @Bungo $abba = e$, so $abbaba = ba = ab$?

Comment: Right, $abbaba = ba$, and the LHS equals $ab$ since $baba = e$.

Comment: @Bungo thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic exercise:

> If $g^2=e$ for all $g \in G$, then $G$ is commutative.

The standard hint is to consider $g=ab$ noting that $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g$:

> $ab = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = ba$

Answer (score 3):

I believe your question about your attempted proof boils down to the following: If we know that
$$ c a = a d$$
for some $a,c,d$ in a group $G$, then can we conclude that $c = d$?

And the answer is **no** --- additional information is necessary. For a counterexample, look to any nonabelian group, like the Dihedral group of six elements $S_3$. The elements $(123)(23) = (13)(123)$, but $(23) \neq (13)$.

So your attempted proof is incorrect. lhf's answer contains the classic approach to a correct proof.