# Proof that a group is abelian if every square is the identity.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

I need to prove that for $(\mathbf G, \circ)$ a group, if for every $a\in\mathbf G$ $$a\circ a=e$$ where $e$ is identity element of that group, then the group is abelian group.$$\\$$My proof:
$$\text{We know that:}\\a\circ e=a=e\circ a\\b\circ e=b=e\circ b\\b\circ b=e=a\circ a\text{, so if}\\a\circ a=b\circ b\text{, then}\\a\circ (e\circ a)=(e\circ b)\circ b\\a\circ(b\circ b\circ a)=(a\circ a\circ b)\circ b\\(a\circ b)\circ (b\circ a)=(a\circ a)\circ(b\circ b)=e\circ e=e\\(a\circ b)\circ (b\circ a)=e\Rightarrow a\circ b=b\circ a$$
And I'm not really sure of the last step. Is this proof proper?

Comment: Your last line needs explanation: Since $(ab)(ab)=(ab)^2=e,$  and since you have derived $(ab)(ba)=e,$  we have $(ab)(ab)=(ab(ba)\iff ab=ba.$. But it's ok.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2039640/589.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your proof is correct as others pointed out (although the last line might require further clarification). Let me provide a shorter way though:

\begin{align}
a \circ b &= \underbrace{(b\circ b)}_{e} \circ (a \circ b) \circ \underbrace{(a\circ a)}_{e} \\
&= b\circ \underbrace{((b \circ a) \circ( b \circ a))}_{e}\circ a \\
&= b \circ a 
\end{align}

Comment: Why didn't I think of it? Thanks a lot, that's much easier than my proof.

Comment: @R.K. It takes some trial and error :) Anyway you are welcome.

Answer (score 9):

The proof is valid if you meant $a^2=e$ **for all $a\in G$** at the beginning. Here's a variant:

We can read $(ab)^2=e$ as $ab=(ab)^{-1}$. Thus from the general rule of computing product inverses
$$
ab=b^{-1}a^{-1}.
$$
But also $a^2=b^2=e$, so that $a^{-1}=a$ and $b^{-1}=b$. Plugging in the previous displayed formula we get
$$
ab=ba.
$$

Comment: Yes, I meant that it's for all the elements from G. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Well, it can be simplified by noting that $a^2=e$ implies $a=a^{-1}$, so $ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$.

Comment: @egreg ... and that is *exactly* what I did!

Answer (score 3):

The last step is not good: there are groups where you have elements $x,y$ satisfying $xyyx = e$ and $xy \neq yx$, so on its own, knowing $abba = e$ is not sufficient to conclude $ab = ba$.

Answer (score 2):

The third line is incorrect. You cannot get that $b\circ b = e$ (consider $\mathbb{Z}_4^+$, where $2 + 2 = 0$ but $1+1 \neq 0$).

Comment: I edited. It says 'for EVERY a'. Is this correct now?

Comment: @R.K. The last step is not invalid but I suspect that the reasoning you are following to justify it is not sound. From the second-to-last equality we find that $(a\circ b)^{-1} = (b\circ a)$. On the other hand, as every element has order $2$, $(a\circ b)^{-1} = (a\circ b)$ and that justifies it. See the other answers for a better proof style though. You do too much unnecessary work.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is nearly there. You have shown that $(a \circ b)$ is the inverse of $(b \circ a)$.

Now you can multiply by $(b \circ a)$ and combine that with the knowledge that $(b \circ a)\circ(b \circ a)=e$ :
\begin{align}
(a \circ b)\circ(b \circ a) &= e \\
(a \circ b)\circ(b \circ a)\circ(b \circ a) &= e\circ(b \circ a) \\
(a \circ b)\circ e &= (b \circ a) \\
(a \circ b) &= (b \circ a) \\
\end{align}