# Which groups satisfy the condition that the square of every element is in the centre of the group?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ be a group satisfying that $ab^2=b^2a$ for every $a,b\in G$. Equivalently, this means that the square of every element is in the centre $Z(G)$. The following groups are examples:

1. Every Abelian group satisfies this condition trivially.
2. The [quatenion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$ satisfies this condition.
3. The [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) $D_8$ satisfies this condition.

**Question**: Is there a name for the groups that satisfy this condition? What else can we say about such groups? What are other examples of such groups?

Comment: This is equivalent to saying that the quotient group $Q=G/Z(G)$ has the property that every element has order $2$. It follows that $Q$ is abelian, see for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039632/my-proof-towards-showing-that-g2-e-implies-that-g-is-commutative/2039640#2039640. So then one can also say that your group is solvable.

Comment: Note that every element g in group G induces an automorphism x -> gxg^(-1).  If all the automorphisms are trivial then the group is automatically abelian.  But your condition means that square of automorphisms are identity.  I'm not sure how to extend this but I guess it does help a bit.

Comment: One can easily see that such a group is nilpotent of class at most $2$. Assuming it's finite, that means that we can write $G=P_2\times P_{2'}$, where $P_2$ is the Sylow $2$-subgroup. Moroever, one can then easily see that $P_{2'}$ is abelian, so the question reduces to $2$-groups. You can say a little more, but not much more, because this family of groups is very large. (I think it's conjectured that almost all $2$-groups (and in fact almost all finite groups) have this property...)

Answer (score 0):

One can easily see that such a group is nilpotent of class at most 2. Assuming it's finite, that means that we can write $G=P_2\times P_2′$, where $P_2$ is the Sylow $2$-subgroup. Moreover, one can then easily see that $P_2′$ is abelian, so the question reduces to $2$-groups. You can say a little more, but not much more, because this family of $2$-groups is very large. (I think it's conjectured that almost all $2$-groups (and in fact almost all finite groups) have this property...)